# Profile component Error when deploying using ANT

Tags: deployment, profile, ant, system-admin

im trying to deploy System Admin Standard profile from one Org to another one.

We are getting this error:
All Component Failures:

1. profiles/Admin.profile -- Error: The user license doesn't allow the permission: PermitImpersonation

Ive already search on the profile metadata for that user permission but couldnt find any. Also on the profile metadata on the Org were we are deploying.
Tried to do a deploy checkOnly to a sandbox with the package.xml and profile and the error did not show up.

Looked for a solution but seems that nobody got this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version are you on? This may or may not help, but better than nothing! https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3pNAAS&title=error-profiles-admin-profile-admin-the-user-license-doesn-t-allow-the-permission-createworkbadgedefinition

Comment: We are using API version 41